# How can I delete a uicollectionviewcell from collection view using longtapGesture on the cell that I want to remove? swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

how can I delete a selected item using longtap gesture from collection view and display reloaded data since I am unable to do it using indexpath.row method. I am using UIAlertAction to achieve this action. But cannot hit the cell on longtapGesture.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let mainstoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let detailVC = mainstoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detailVC") as! DetailVC
        detailVC.image = Model.dataList[indexPath.item].image
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)

        let tapGes = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didlongPress(tapGes:)))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGes)
    }

//    func removeItem(index : Int){
//        Model.dataList.remove(at: index)
//        
//        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
//        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ 
//            self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
//        }) { (finished : Bool) in
//            self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)
//        }
//    
//    }
//    


    func didlongPress(tapGes : UITapGestureRecognizer){
        let actionController = UIAlertController(title: "Delete", message: "Are You Sure ...?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Current record", style: .default) { (action) in
            print("Deleted")

            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }

        actionController.addAction(action)
        self.present(actionController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionCell
        let note = Model.dataList[indexPath.item]
        cell?.imageView.image = note.image
        cell?.titleLbl.text = note.title


        return cell!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey the following algo will work for you.

- On tap just remove that item from the array "data list" at the
  indexPath by calling "datalist.remove(at: indexPath.row)".
- After that just call "self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])".
- This way you wont have to reload collectionView.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

@Daniyal get IndexPath in your longpress method and then remove value from your array at the index. then reload your collectionview.